# SQL scramble database varchar fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have to create a test database for some external developers to use.

We have created a copy and rather than manually filling it with junk data i want to scramble the text fields.

Are there any easy ways of doing this?

Im using sql server 2005
Sp

Comment: The external developers will be able to do much better testing with original data.  Scrambled data is just not the same.

Comment: That was my argument but "The powers from above" have decided we need to scramble the text field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://blog.seerobcode.com/2007/07/scrambling-client-data-in-sql.html) might help.

Edit: [here's](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=100066) a thread on another forum that may also be of use.

Good luck!

Comment: The link is broken now.

Comment: @devinbost here's the web archive version of that link: https://web.archive.org/web/20110518141400/http://blog.seerobcode.com/2007/07/scrambling-client-data-in-sql.html/

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this is the same as Steven's scenario, but name & surname 'scrambling' is quite common to preserve customer confidentiality when a DB goes from a secure (e.g. Prod) to insecure environment (e.g. Dev, or offsite)

You can select a random row in SQL 
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

So then what you could do is e.g. run a cursor across all rows in the table, selecting a random FirstName row and Surname Row using the above and then updating the current record with the random firstname and surname columns?